# Table's <td> gets wider if I set its content width in pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a big table which contains many smaller tables in it. I need to put some content in these small tables, but when I do, some of the `td's` change its sizes, making others too narrow. Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/jwvzpt62/14/

Content I need to put in tables, is a div `.placeHolder`, it has a red border. Problem occurs when I set width of `.placeHolder` in pixels as you can see. If the width is 100%, it works as it should. How do I fix this? Setting `min-width` did not help. In first table width is 100%, everything is ok, but in second table width is set in pixels. Despite there is enough place in pixels, `.placeHolder` still makes its parent `td` wider and messes up the audio block.

```js
for(var i=1; i<=3; i++){
 var blockId = "channel"+i;
 var aspect = "16:9";
  var aspX = parseInt(aspect.split(':')[0]);
  var aspY = parseInt(aspect.split(':')[1]);
  var width = $('#'+blockId).closest('.channels').find('.vid').width();
  var height = $('#'+blockId).closest('.channels').find('.vid').height();
  var test = (width/aspX)*aspY;
  var test2 = (height/aspY)*aspX;
  if(test <= height){
    $('#'+blockId).closest('.channels').find('.placeHolder').css({'height': test+'px'});
  }
  else {
    $('#'+blockId).closest('.channels').find('.placeHolder').css({'width': test2+'px'});
  }
}
```

```css
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #2c2c2c;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #2c2c2c), color-stop(37%, #3d3d3d), color-stop(66%, #353535), color-stop(66%, #353535), color-stop(100%, #131313));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2c2c2c', endColorstr='#131313', GradientType=1);
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #b8c0c8;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#leftDiv {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
}

#displayItems {
    min-height: auto;
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 3px;
    /*resize: vertical;*/
    overflow: auto;
}

#menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#menu li {
    background: url(images/comment-bg3.png) repeat;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 2px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}

#menu li span {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(images/comment-bg2.png) repeat;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#menu li ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#menu li ul li {
    background: url(images/comment-bg3.png) repeat;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    cursor: move;
}

#menu li ul li:first-child {
    margin-top: 2px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

#menu li ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom: none;
}

#settingsDiv {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#mainDiv {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 85%;
    min-height: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 3px;
}

.channel {
    min-width: 250px;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #515151;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(images/comment-bg3.png) repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
    border-spacing: 0px;
}

.thClass {
    min-width: 150px;
    width: 102%;
    margin-left: -3px;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(images/comment-bg2.png) repeat;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    margin-top: -2px;
    min-height: 30px;
    max-height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 19px;
    cursor: move;
}

.header{
    margin-left: 17px;
}

.tableBody {
    display: block;
    min-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 102%;
    margin-left: -2px;
    cursor: default;
}

.channel tbody tr td {
    display: block;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

#settingsDiv {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.settings {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.add {
    display: block;
    width: 102%;
    margin-left: -3px;
    background: url(images/comment-rowsubmit.png) repeat-x;
    min-height: 20px;
}

.addList{
    width: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.addList:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: antiquewhite;
}

.draggableItems {
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-y: auto !important;
}

.draggableItems::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: url(images/comment-bg.png) repeat;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.draggableItems::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: url(images/comment-bg3.png) repeat;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.draggableItems::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: url(images/bg-tabs.png) repeat;
}

.draggableItems::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
    background: linear-gradient(left, #22ADD4, #1E98BA);
}

#displaySizes {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
 max-width: 100px;
}

.disp tbody tr th {
    column-span: all;
}

.disp tbody tr td {
    display: table-cell;
}

.ui-resizable {
 position: absolute !important;
 width: 250px;
}

#mainDiv .container {
 width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
}

#mainContainer {
 width: 1926px;
 height: 1086px;
}

#dispInfo {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(images/comment-bg2.png);
}

.videoDropped {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
}

.screens{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.channels {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(images/comment-bg3.png) repeat;
}

.channels td {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
}

.channels td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.channelHeader {
  height: 7%;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(images/comment-bg2.png) repeat;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
}

.audioVideo {
  height: 79%;
}

.channelInfo {
  height: 7%;
  max-height: 7%;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(images/comment-bg2.png) repeat;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
}

.channelInfo td {
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}

.channelInfoValues {
  height: 7%;
  max-height: 7%;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  width: 100%;
 background: url(images/rsz_buttons.png);
 background-size: cover;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 height: 22px;
 color: #b8c0c8;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 4px;
 outline: none;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
}

.btn:hover {
 background: url(images/hover_buttons.png) no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 border: none;
 color: white;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

.cpu {
  width: 120px;
  height: 70px;
  min-width: 120px;
  min-height: 70px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  resize: none;
  padding: 7px;
}

.cpu:hover {
  resize: both;
}

/*Audio styling*/

.sound {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.audiodb {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.levels {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 17%;
  top: 5%;
  height: 1px;
  left: 30%;
  background: silver;
  z-index: 300;
}

.level1 {
  top: 13%;
}

.level2 {
  top: 20%;
}

.level3 {
  top: 30%;
}

.level4 {
  top: 45%;
}

.level5 {
  top: 61%;
}

.level6 {
  top: 78%;
}

.level7 {
  top: 95%;
}

.audioBackground {
  width: 15%;
  height: 90%;
  left: 53%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  background: #ff0000;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 7%, #faff00 20%, #00ff2a 38%, #006d10 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ff0000), color-stop(7%,#ff0000), color-stop(20%,#faff00), color-stop(38%,#00ff2a), color-stop(100%,#006d10)); /* Chrome4-9,Safari4-5 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 7%,#faff00 20%,#00ff2a 38%,#006d10 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 7%,#faff00 20%,#00ff2a 38%,#006d10 100%); /* Opera 11.10-11.50 */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 7%,#faff00 20%,#00ff2a 38%,#006d10 100%); /* IE10 preview */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 7%,#faff00 20%,#00ff2a 38%,#006d10 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff0000', endColorstr='#006d10',GradientType=0 );
  overflow: hidden;
}

.audioRight {
  left: 71%;
}

.audioCover {
  width: 200%;
  height: 30%;
  background: grey;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
.audioNumbers {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}
.db {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
}
.db p {
  margin-top: -5px;
}
.max {
  top: 5%;
}
.high {
  top: 15%;
}
.normal {
  top: 35%;
}
.low {
  top: 95%;
}

#mainContainer {
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: 0 0 0;
  transform: translate(0,0) scale(1);
}

.placeHolder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="leftDiv">
        <div id="deviceInfo">
            <ul id="menu">
            <li>Device Name
                <ul id="deviceName">
                    <li>
                      item 1
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Interface
                <ul id="interface">
                    <li>
                      item 2
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="settingsDiv">
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainDiv">
      <div id="mainContainer" class="ui-droppable"><table class="screens ui-draggable" dispcoords="0x0" dispresolution="1920x1080" style="position: relative;"><tbody class="ui-draggable-handle"><tr class="screensRow ui-draggable-handle"><td class="screenContainer ui-draggable-handle" style="min-width: 478px; height: 358px;"><table class="channels ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-draggable-handle" style="width: 478px; height: 358px; font-size: 11px; max-width: 1920px; max-height: 1080px; position: relative; margin-top: -179px;" oncontextmenu="return false;">            <tbody class="ui-draggable-handle"><tr class="channelHeader ui-draggable-handle">              <td colspan="5" class="channelName ui-draggable-handle" id="channel1" audiopid="0x33" audiostream1="format:mp2,type:audio,pid:0x33,width:0,height:0,language:geo" interface="192.168.222.38" method="info" multicast="239.10.20.101" port="6000" protocol="udp" resolution="1920x1080" serviceid="1" servicename="Imedi" serviceprovider="Stereo +" videopid="0x31" videostream="format:H264,type:video,pid:0x31,width:1920,height:1080" aspect="16:9" fps="25">Imedi</td><td colspan="2" class="channelNumber ui-draggable-handle">1</td>            </tr>            <tr class="audioVideo ui-draggable-handle">              <td colspan="5" class="vid ui-draggable-handle"><div class="placeHolder ui-draggable-handle" style="height: 236.813px;"></div></td><td colspan="2" class="sound ui-draggable-handle"><div class="audiodb ui-draggable-handle">              <div class="audioNumbers ui-draggable-handle">                <span class="db max level0 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">0</p></span>                <span class="db high level1 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-6</p></span>                <span class="db level2 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-12</p></span>                <span class="db normal level3 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-20</p></span>                <span class="db level4 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-30</p></span>                <span class="db level5 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-40</p></span>                <span class="db level6 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-50</p></span>                <span class="db low level7 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-60</p></span>              </div>              <div class="audioBackground audioLeft ui-draggable-handle">                <div class="audioCover ui-draggable-handle" style="height: 8%;"></div>              </div>              <div class="audioBackground audioRight ui-draggable-handle">                <div class="audioCover ui-draggable-handle" style="height: 8%;"></div>              </div>              <span class="levels level0 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level1 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level2 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level3 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level4 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level5 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level6 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level7 ui-draggable-handle"></span>            </div></td>            </tr>            <tr class="channelInfo ui-draggable-handle">              <td class="resolution ui-draggable-handle">Resolution</td><td class="aspect ui-draggable-handle">Aspect</td><td class="fps ui-draggable-handle">FPS</td><td class="vformat ui-draggable-handle">V-Format</td><td class="aformat ui-draggable-handle">A-Format</td><td class="ui-draggable-handle">L</td><td class="ui-draggable-handle">R</td>            </tr>            <tr class="channelInfoValues ui-draggable-handle">              <td class="resolValue ui-draggable-handle">1920x1080</td><td class="aspectValue ui-draggable-handle">16:9</td><td class="fpsValue ui-draggable-handle">25</td><td class="vformatValue ui-draggable-handle">H264</td><td class="aformatValue ui-draggable-handle">MP2</td><td class="leftBarValue ui-draggable-handle">---</td><td class="rightBarValue ui-draggable-handle">---</td>            </tr>          </tbody><div class="resize-sensor ui-draggable-handle" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;"><div class="resize-sensor-expand ui-draggable-handle" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; overflow: hidden; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transition: 0s; width: 100000px; height: 100000px;" class="ui-draggable-handle"></div></div><div class="resize-sensor-shrink ui-draggable-handle" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; overflow: hidden; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; transition: 0s; width: 200%; height: 200%" class="ui-draggable-handle"></div></div></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e ui-draggable-handle" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s ui-draggable-handle" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se ui-draggable-handle" style="z-index: 90;"></div></table></td><td class="screenContainer ui-draggable-handle" style="min-width: 478px; height: 358px;"><table class="channels ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-draggable-handle" style="width: 478px; height: 358px; font-size: 11px; max-width: 1920px; max-height: 1080px; position: relative; margin-top: -179px;" oncontextmenu="return false;">            <tbody class="ui-draggable-handle"><tr class="channelHeader ui-draggable-handle">              <td colspan="5" class="channelName ui-draggable-handle" id="channel2" audiopid="0x33" audiostream1="format:mp2,type:audio,pid:0x33,width:0,height:0,language:geo" interface="192.168.222.38" method="info" multicast="239.10.20.103" port="6000" protocol="udp" resolution="720x576" serviceid="3" servicename="RUSTAVI 2" serviceprovider="Stereo +" videopid="0x31" videostream="format:H264,type:video,pid:0x31,width:720,height:576" aspect="15:11" fps="25">RUSTAVI 2</td><td colspan="2" class="channelNumber ui-draggable-handle">2</td>            </tr>            <tr class="audioVideo ui-draggable-handle">              <td colspan="5" class="vid ui-draggable-handle"><div class="placeHolder ui-draggable-handle" style="width: 383.182px;"></div></td><td colspan="2" class="sound ui-draggable-handle"><div class="audiodb ui-draggable-handle">              <div class="audioNumbers ui-draggable-handle">                <span class="db max level0 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">0</p></span>                <span class="db high level1 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-6</p></span>                <span class="db level2 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-12</p></span>                <span class="db normal level3 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-20</p></span>                <span class="db level4 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-30</p></span>                <span class="db level5 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-40</p></span>                <span class="db level6 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-50</p></span>                <span class="db low level7 ui-draggable-handle"><p style="margin-top: -5.5px;" class="ui-draggable-handle">-60</p></span>              </div>              <div class="audioBackground audioLeft ui-draggable-handle">                <div class="audioCover ui-draggable-handle" style="height: 8%;"></div>              </div>              <div class="audioBackground audioRight ui-draggable-handle">                <div class="audioCover ui-draggable-handle" style="height: 8%;"></div>              </div>              <span class="levels level0 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level1 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level2 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level3 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level4 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level5 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level6 ui-draggable-handle"></span>              <span class="levels level7 ui-draggable-handle"></span>            </div></td>            </tr>            <tr class="channelInfo ui-draggable-handle">              <td class="resolution ui-draggable-handle">Resolution</td><td class="aspect ui-draggable-handle">Aspect</td><td class="fps ui-draggable-handle">FPS</td><td class="vformat ui-draggable-handle">V-Format</td><td class="aformat ui-draggable-handle">A-Format</td><td class="ui-draggable-handle">L</td><td class="ui-draggable-handle">R</td>            </tr>            <tr class="channelInfoValues ui-draggable-handle">              <td class="resolValue ui-draggable-handle">720x576</td><td class="aspectValue ui-draggable-handle">15:11</td><td class="fpsValue ui-draggable-handle">25</td><td class="vformatValue ui-draggable-handle">H264</td><td class="aformatValue ui-draggable-handle">MP2</td><td class="leftBarValue ui-draggable-handle">---</td><td class="rightBarValue ui-draggable-handle">---</td>            </tr>          </tbody><div class="resize-sensor ui-draggable-handle" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;"><div class="resize-sensor-expand ui-draggable-handle" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; overflow: hidden; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transition: 0s; width: 100000px; height: 100000px;" class="ui-draggable-handle"></div></div><div class="resize-sensor-shrink ui-draggable-handle" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; overflow: hidden; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; transition: 0s; width: 200%; height: 200%" class="ui-draggable-handle"></div></div></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e ui-draggable-handle" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s ui-draggable-handle" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se ui-draggable-handle" style="z-index: 90;"></div></table></td><td class="screenContainer ui-draggable-handle" style="min-width: 478px; height: 358px;"></td><td class="screenContainer ui-draggable-handle" style="min-width: 478px; height: 358px;"></td></tr><tr class="screensRow ui-draggable-handle"><td class="screenContainer ui-draggable-handle" style="min-width: 478px; height: 358px;"></td><td class="screenContainer ui-draggable-handle" style="min-width: 478px; height: 358px;"></td><td class="screenContainer ui-draggable-handle" style="min-width: 478px; height: 358px;"></td><td class="screenContainer ui-draggable-handle" style="min-width: 478px; height: 358px;"></td></tr></tbody></table></div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. (ie not in a jsfiddle)

Comment: That's a lot of code (I see why you didn't include it in the question) - but you should be able to create an [mcve] to show the issue.  Specifically a *minimal* example that reproduces it - should be able to recreate the issue in less than 20 lines.

Comment: "set width in pixels" - set width of what?  The table?  the .placeHolder?   Can you describe what you're trying to do?  `table` is designed to fit to content unless you specify the column width either in %age or pixels (per column).  Maybe you would be better off not using a table?

Comment: You could try `table-layout: fixed` to `.channels`

Comment: @freedomn-m I managed to include the working code

Comment: @VijayDev I tried, but it gives undesirable sizes to all cells. I need to keep the proportions I have in my tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you mix px with %. Do not do that! It messes up layout calculation in the browser. I would suggest using only % to specify column widths and make sure you always have a total of 100% for all cols.

Comment: Good point! Now I calculate desired pixels in percentage and it works well. Thank you.

Comment: If you need to set a minimum width, set it on the entire outer table and use only % inside it